# Simple Destructuring Program - ES6 (JavaScript) throwing error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to make a simple destructuring and return value by a function. But, it is throwing error. Can someone help me out?

**Example:**

```html
<script>
obj1 = {
name: "Jack Rogers",
age: 29,
city: 'New York',
country: 'USA',
}

increaseAge(someObj, val){
let {age} = someObj;
return age+val;
}

console.log(increaseAge(obj1, 5));
</script>
```

I was expecting '34' in result (console).

Comment: You are missing the `function` keyword before `increaseAge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write [**function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) before **increaseAge**

```js
obj1 = {
    name: "Jack Rogers",
    age: 29,
    city: 'New York',
    country: 'USA',
}

function increaseAge(someObj, val){
    let {age} = someObj;
    return age+val;
}

console.log(increaseAge(obj1, 5));
```